# Redacting images on deleted posts

Tags: discussion, editing

Personally I sort answer by newest on questions.

On the question [What animal could strip all the bark off the lower 7 feet of this tree?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/q/14789/4079) there were multiple new **NOT answers** that contained images and had been deleted.  I got tired of scrolling past them (*high rep users see deleted posts in pink highlights*)

I edited all the **NOT Answers**, replacing the image with 'Redact image to collapse deleted post'

If any one has objections or support for my actions, here is your opportunity to voice them :)

*P.S. Thank you to Charlie for protecting the question.*

Comment: If you sort answers by votes (which seems like the most useful in almost every situation), the deleted answers are at the bottom so you don't need to scroll past them.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Because if you read the new answers to old questions, it nice not have to scroll all of the ways to the bottom to see what caused the post to be bumped to the home page

Comment: @CharlieBrumbaugh Instead of clicking the question title on the home page, click the "Modified/answered 10 minutes ago" link, which takes you straight to the modified content without having to scroll past anything.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I have never heard of or seen a 'Modified/answered 10 minutes ago' link.  I am looking around and not seeing it.  Maybe it only exists for 10 minutes and I don't visit the site every 9 minutes?

Comment: @JamesJenkins https://i.stack.imgur.com/OdHfe.jpg

Comment: @DavidRicherby, I use that modified/answered link all the time, so I can find out exactly what happened to a post!  Someone on another site taught it to me, and  I found it's good for a lot of things!

Comment: I had no idea that was a link...

Comment: Hi James, I respectfully disagree with doing this on a regular basis. However, if it continues, there's a compromise option. A user could write "redacted image to collapse deleted post. To see the image, click on the [edit history](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/posts/18059/revisions). That "edit" would be the link we've been discussing. That way you've told people something is there and given them an easy way to see it.

Comment: James, this could be picky, but the correct grammar for "redact" would be "redacted" because by the time someone reads it, it will have been past tense. Also, putting it in parentheses would set it apart from the actual text. I hope I didn't insult you or your grammatical skills!

Comment: @Sue I don't think it is going to happen often enough to be concerned about specifics of message or grammar.  I am always open to grammar suggestions.

Answer (score 5):

I absolutely support it! They are already non-answers so additional content is irrelevant. If the owner edits to make them actual answers, they can reinsert the image if needed.

Comment: Then why not delete the whole text of the answer, too?

Comment: Yes - we could do that too, @David, but that doesn't help the poster edit their question. It can be good for them to have the text to ensure they are reminded.

Comment: Hi Rory, I have a procedural question. To change anything in a deleted answer, don't you have to undelete it? During that short period before deleting it again, wouldn't it be considered active and get bumped to the home page, or does it all happen so fast that the system doesn't do that? Can you explain that please, so I don't have the wrong impression? Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Sue - The author can edit while it is deleted and then get it undeleted again.

Comment: @Sue all post edits bring it to the top of the active posts list.  Without regard for the post being deleted or not. Delete does not really mean delete so much as it means hid for users under a specific rep limit (and OP can see) and give it that pink deleted post format. Scroll down in the recent activity until you find my edit on that tree post, the recent edit link will take you to my redact.

Comment: Rory and James, I'm sorry for taking so long to thank you for answering my question! I appreciate your time!